# SQL - Split string to columns by multiple delimiters

Tags: sql, sql-server, string, delimiter

There appear to be numerous solutions to this problem, however my solutions needs to be dynamic as the number of delimiters changes from between 0 and 3 and needs to be relatively efficient as it will be running across >10m rows across 5 loops.

As example:

```
  US

  US-AL

  US-AL-Talladega

  US-AL-Talladega-35160
```

The solution would need to be able to deposit each item in a Country, State, County, ZIP field with a NULL field if the information is not within the string.

Any comments on the best approach would be appreciated or even point me in the direction of where I may have possible missed a solution would be much appreciated

Comment: Or any other language but I am stuck with SQL Server for this solution. Multiple substring / charindex combinations is the current solution I am working on but it is in no way the most efficient!

Comment: Which version of SQL Server?

Comment: Post the code that you're using.

Answer (score 2):

Another option is with a little XML in concert with a CROSS or OUTER APPLY

**Example**

```
Declare @YourTable table (YourCol varchar(100))
Insert Into @YourTable values
 ('US')
,('US-AL')
,('US-AL-Talladega')
,('US-AL-Talladega-35160')

Select A.* 
      ,B.*
 From @YourTable A
 Outer Apply (
                Select Country = xDim.value('/x[1]','varchar(max)')
                      ,State   = xDim.value('/x[2]','varchar(max)')
                      ,County  = xDim.value('/x[3]','varchar(max)')
                      ,ZIP     = xDim.value('/x[4]','varchar(max)')
                From  (Select Cast('<x>' + replace(YourCol,'-','</x><x>')+'</x>' as xml) as xDim) as A 
             ) B
```

Returns

```
YourCol                 Country State   County      ZIP
US                      US      NULL    NULL        NULL
US-AL                   US      AL      NULL        NULL
US-AL-Talladega         US      AL      Talladega   NULL
US-AL-Talladega-35160   US      AL      Talladega   35160
```

Answer (score 0):

you will need a delimited splitter. Like `DelimitedSplit8K` from http://www.sqlservercentral.com/articles/Tally+Table/72993/

```
; with tbl as
(
    select  col = 'US'          union all
    select  col = 'US-AL'           union all
    select  col = 'US-AL-Talladega'     union all
    select  col = 'US-AL-Talladega-35160'
)
select  t.col,
        max(case when ItemNumber = 1 then Item end) as Country,
        max(case when ItemNumber = 2 then Item end) as State,
        max(case when ItemNumber = 3 then Item end) as County,
        max(case when ItemNumber = 4 then Item end) as Zip
from    tbl t
        cross apply dbo.[DelimitedSplit8K](t.col, '-')
group by t.col
```