# SQL - Split string multiple values, multiple values

Tags: sql, t-sql, sql-server-2014

I'm looking to split a string of delimited dates into their respective values and place them within columns of a results table. I've had some success with the following, not quite there for my specific application
[SQL - Split string to columns by multiple delimiters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52149073/sql-split-string-to-columns-by-multiple-delimiters)

```
String (from & to dates)
tblTempDates.tmpString
2019-2-11--2019-2-15,2019-2-20--2019-2-20,2019-2-23--2019-2-23,2019-3-19--2019-3-24

Delimiters
-- seperates from & to
, new record

Output required
tblTempDates2
dtFrom        dtTo
2019-02-11    2019-02-15
2019-02-20    2019-02-20
2019-02-23    2019-02-23
2019-02-19    2019-03-24
```

Many thanks in advance :-)

Comment: Are you really using `--` as a delimiter? This is ill advised as `--` denotes a comment

Comment: Thanks for the comment - I'm not precious on the delimiter character as such.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can use while statement to split the csv,

```
    declare @a table(datefromto varchar(500))

    declare @b table(fromdate varchar(500),todate varchar(500))

    insert into @a values ('2019-2-11--2019-2-15,2019-2-20--2019-2-20,2019-2-23--2019-2-23,2019-3-19--2019-3-24');

    declare @datefromto varchar(500) = (select max(datefromto) from @a)

    declare @datesplit int
    set @datesplit= (SELECT charindex(',',@datefromto))



    WHILE (SELECT charindex(',',@datefromto) FROM @a) <> 0
    BEGIN  



       insert into @b select Left(left(@datefromto,@datesplit),charindex('--',@datefromto)-1) ,
       Right(left(@datefromto,@datesplit-1),charindex('--',@datefromto)-1) from @a


       set @datesplit= (SELECT charindex(',',@datefromto))
       set @datefromto= right(@datefromto,len(@datefromto)-@datesplit)

    END  
       insert into @b select Left(left(@datefromto,@datesplit),charindex('--',@datefromto)-1) ,
       Right(left(@datefromto,@datesplit-1),charindex('--',@datefromto)-1) from @a

    select * from @b
```

Comment: This partially works - in that it gets the very first date and the very last but nothing in between (2019-02-11 ... 2019-03-24) - so a single row only

Comment: It also leaves out the splitting CSV to rows step; not a minor step.

Comment: Understood your problem involves the comma separated list as well, I have modified the query with a while loop can you give it a try.

Comment: @BigIWT Were you able to try this?

Comment: Hi, yes just now - we're almost there actually. It works but needs to be able to handle day & month lengths - some are single digits, some are double (2019-1-1) (2019-1-31) (2019-10-1) (2019-10-30) - thanks in advance

Comment: @AjanBalakumaran There are much better approaches. Using a `WHILE` loop is *procedural thinking* and should be avoided if ever possible...

Comment: Actually, I'm looking at how I'm getting standard data into the db, so your solution @AjanBalakumaran may work - i'll be back

Comment: @BigIWT I'm glad for you, that you found a working solution. I just feel obliged to point out, that this approach to split a string has so many draw backs and flaws, that I'd really think about this once again... Anyway Happy Coding!

Answer (score 0):

Here is one nice way to do this using `STRING_SPLIT`, if your version of SQL Server supports it:

```
SELECT
    LEFT(value, CHARINDEX('--', value) - 1) AS dtFrom,
    SUBSTRING(value, CHARINDEX('--', value) + 2, 20) AS dtTo
FROM
(
    SELECT STRING_SPLIT(input, ',')
    FROM yourTable
) t;
```

This approach first splits each from/to date substring to a separate row by comma using `STRING_SPLIT`.  Then, it uses base string functions to isolate the from and to dates.

Comment: Thanks - using SQL 2014

Comment: Then you will have to use some other method to split each CSV value to a separate row.  But, my outer query logic should still work.

Comment: I have a similar SplitString function, when using, your suggested code, it spits out the same dates repeatedly, as opposed to  each row being seperated. Also, the date charindex will change depending on the day/month length ... thanks

Answer (score 0):

with versions before `STRING_SPLIT()` (or `OPENJSON`) I'd suggest this approach:

```
DECLARE @tbl TABLE(ID INT IDENTITY, YourString VARCHAR(1000));
INSERT INTO @tbl VALUES('2019-2-11--2019-2-15,2019-2-20--2019-2-20,2019-2-23--2019-2-23,2019-3-19--2019-3-24');

WITH Casted AS
(
    SELECT *
         , CAST('<x><y>' + REPLACE(REPLACE(YourString,'--','</y><y>'),',','</y></x><x><y>') + '</y></x>' AS XML) AsXml
    FROM @tbl 
)
SELECT  ID 
       ,x.value('y[1]','date') AS Date1
       ,x.value('y[2]','date') AS Date2
FROM Casted
CROSS APPLY AsXml.nodes('/x') A(x);
```

The idea in short:

Some string replacements transform your *multi-level-CSV* into an XML like this

```
<x>
  <y>2019-2-11</y>
  <y>2019-2-15</y>
</x>
<x>
  <y>2019-2-20</y>
  <y>2019-2-20</y>
</x>
<x>
  <y>2019-2-23</y>
  <y>2019-2-23</y>
</x>
<x>
  <y>2019-3-19</y>
  <y>2019-3-24</y>
</x>
```

We can then use `.nodes()` to get all repeating `<x>` as derived table. Then we use `.value()` to fetch the `<y>` by their position.